# Folder Dialog return to dialog if criteria not met

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, folderbrowserdialog, ookii

I'm using the Ookii Vista folder dialog for ease of use, and I have this code going on which is called from a button:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Ookii.Dialogs;

private string LoadDirectories()
{
    VistaFolderBrowserDialog fbd = new VistaFolderBrowserDialog();
    if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && fbd.SelectedPath.Contains("U000"))
    {
        return fbd.SelectedPath;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Folder must be root assembly, which has U000 in name");
    }
    
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Currently, if the user does not pick a folder with `U000` in the name, the dialog will close, but I want it to stay open until user either cancels or sets the correct folder path. I can't find this anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple realization of your needs (Add a `while`):

Used nuget: `Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf`

```
private string LoadDirectories()
{
    VistaFolderBrowserDialog fbd = new VistaFolderBrowserDialog();
    while (true)
    {
        if (fbd.ShowDialog() == false)
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (fbd.SelectedPath.Contains("U000"))
        {

            return fbd.SelectedPath;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Folder must be root assembly, which has U000 in name");
        }
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

output：

[image]

Comment: wow so simple, and I was bugged about it so much, thanks!